# Type callback as function that takes an argument of one of several possible types

Tags: typescript

I believe this must be possible in typescript, but I haven't yet reached the level of typescriptt enlightenment required to express this.

I am trying to type a simple pub/sub service. The service will have a `subscribe` function that takes a callback function and adds it in an array of functions to be called when a message arrives. What I am trying to achieve is to type the callback function passed to the `subscribe` function.  Here's a simplified version of the code ([click to see it in typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgYwPYFsCWcDmBZCBnPAQ0wgEYoBeKAbwCgoGpCFg0k4AuKAcgDMkk3ANz1GYQiAA2SQgBMu1KKMaN%20SLnACuKAEYQATiJVQAvrRMjaoSLESoMOfERIAmSjWVMWbTjx2F9YU9xKRl5GiVjRn99DW09Q09Tc0traHhkdCxcAmJoKgz7bKc88gAfW0yHHOcIF0tkODxgKF44cioAChQSki5CrMdcklIASkoAPh40JhQofQhgTX04Byg8VEWACwcg2kbm1rg3Lp7hiH67QZq8l3GKKboVAHpnqBnCObgkFoWllbWhDgIGAOywKVokIOLWahDwWy4AEF9PoJAAeNHYKAQAAewAgcFkeEqRSGtQm3V6Fyg2HuU00cAA1t8AO5wKZUADaAF0GuxDnhNDo8Ah9Gg9O5Mdi8QSiSTrlSKQhCJJJP4EIyuJTzlxaZMoAzmUg2XSPCpYfCAHRgTTwzrK1XqxmjEQWSGC4Wi8UQTptMYiIA)).

```
type IncomingMessage1 = {
    action: 'foo';
    payload: { 
        foo: number;
     }
};

type IncomingMessage2 = {
    action: 'bar';
    payload: { 
        bar: number;
     }
};

type IncomingMessage = IncomingMessage1 | IncomingMessage2;

const fn1 = (message: IncomingMessage1) => 'i am returning something';

const fn2 = (message: IncomingMessage2) => {
    // i am not returning anything
};


const stash: Array<<M extends IncomingMessage>(message: M) => unknown> = [];

const subscribe = <M extends IncomingMessage>(callback: (message: M) => unknown) => {
    stash.push(callback);
};

subscribe(fn1);
```

This is, of course, wrong (typescript shows error at `stash.push(callback)`), because each callback function takes one of the message types, but only one of them, not a union of them. Is there a way to properly type the callback function passed as an argument to the `subscribe` **based on the type of the IncomingMessage argument alone**? I believe that if I just created a union type of callback functions themselves and passed it to the `subscribe`, it would be happy; but I don't want to do that, and I suspect there is be a way of doing it without expressly listing the types of fn1, fn2, etc.

Comment: The type of your array stipulates that every function in it can accept either an `IncomingMessage1` or an `IncomingMessage2`. You are trying to add functions to it that require _either_ one _or_ the other. This would no be type safe because it means you could write `stash = []; stash.push(fn1); stash[0]({ action: 'bar', payload: { bar: 5 } });` and therefore the language disallows it.

Comment: You might want to rethink your approach. Perhaps maintain separate collections of callbacks keyed by the action type. It really depends on the use case. Can you show how you invoke the functions?

Comment: @AluanHaddad You are right! Since the callback functions are added to the common array of callbacks, they must be capable of handling the whole union of incoming messages. I'll try to rethink the approach. Perhaps `IncomingMessage1` type and `IncomingMessage2` type can both extend the more abstract `IncomingMessage` type; and that would be the more appropriate representation of what's actually going on.

Comment: I don't think a common supertype will help. It really matters how you are going to invoke them. I am imaging that you will receive some `IncomingMessage` and test its `action` property to determine which kind it is so you can access the payload appropriately.

Comment: I am reviewing my pub/sub service; and yes, the subscriber callbacks were initially supposed to go into different arrays, probably kept in a hash keyed by the `action` string; so that all functions within an array would receive the same type of message. Otherwise, as you rightly point out, every subscriber would have to check the `action` property to decide which type of a message it has received.

Comment: I think that initial design sounds elegant